# Many to Many Relationship - how to query all children

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sqlalchemy to implement many to many relationship. Tried many options but unable to query all children for a parent.

```
class Participant(db.Model):
    __tablename__='participant'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship("User")

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_user(user):
        return Participant.query.filter_by(user=user).first()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(Participant '{}')".format(self.email)

    competitions = db.relationship("CompetitionParticipant", back_populates="participant")

class Competition(db.Model): 
    __tablename__='competition'
    __table_args__={'extend_existing':True}

    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)

    name=db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True)
    description=db.Column(db.String(255),unique=True)
    # type=db.Column(db.String(50))#Team,Individual,Practice,etc.
    start_date=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    end_date=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    result_date=db.Column(db.DateTime)

    participants = db.relationship('CompetitionParticipant', back_populates='competition')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(Competition '{}')".format(self.name)

class CompetitionParticipant(db.Model): 
    __tablename__='competition_participant'
    __table_args__={'extend_existing':True}

    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    participant_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('participant.id'))
    competition_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('competition.id'))

    competition=db.relationship("Competition",back_populates="participants")
    participant=db.relationship("Participant",back_populates="competitions")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(competition_id, participant_id '{},{}')".format(self.competition_id,self.participant_id)
```

In this many to many relationship example how will I query all the competitions a participant is enrolled in?

I have tried following:

```
participant.competitions # returns relationship object
```

everything else I tried was syntax error. What is right ORM way to extract all competitions a participant is enrolled in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you, for example, want to get competitions data for a specific user:

```
participants = Participant.query.filter_by(id=1).all()
```

you can iterate through participants and get data :

```
for participant in participants:
    for competition in participant.competitions:
        print(competition.competition.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be able to do something like this if you wanted to find out about the participant with id=1:

```
participant = Participant.query.get(1)
for item in participant.competitions:
       print(item.name)
```